# how to stop the AWS Redshift resize activity?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Resizing operation seems very very slow

We have ds2.xlarge 3 nodes cluster, we decide to scale down that to 2 nodes, *it has been running for last 28 hours, but the % of completion is just 48% (screenshot attached)*. So,

Do we need to wait for 30+ more hours to get it done, till that the cluster is going to be in read-only mode?

Because of this can we decide that usually resize will take more than 60+ hours?
What if I want to terminate the process?

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: How long did it finally take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

60+ hours is anomalous, as per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/rs-resize-tutorial.html#rs-tutorial-resize-operation-overview) it should take less than 48 hours:

> (resizing) ... can take anywhere from a couple of hours to a couple of days.

You can't stop it from the console, but you can contact AWS support to stop it for you.